# How to create nested object with Mongoose ref connection?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to map data from another Object and create new data on MongoDB.

I have **Video schema** like this

```
const videoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    video_id: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    author: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        ref: 'Author'
    }
})
```

and **Author schema**

```
const authorSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    author_id: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    avatar: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    }
})
```

now I create Object like this and save to DB

```
const videoData = getDataForVideo(requestVideoURL)
        .then(resp => {
            const videoObj = resp.item
            return {
                video_id: videoObj.id,
                author: new Author({
                    author_id: videoObj.author_user_id.toString(),
                    avatar: videoObj.author.avatar,
                }),
            }
        })

await videoData.then(resp => {
        const video = new Video(resp)
        try {
            video.save()
                .then(video => {
                    res.status(201).send({ video })
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    res.status(400).send(err.message)
                })
        } catch (error) {
            res.status(400).send(error)
        }
    })
```

The data of the video saved successfully. But data of the Author is not saved on DB. What is the problem and how to save all data in the right way?

And is the code look ok? I see the saving part is not quite good, I'm not sure how to improve it.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it simple, save one by one in order.

Avoid mixing `async/await` with `.then/.catch`

```js
try {
  const resp = await getDataForVideo(requestVideoURL);
  const videoObj = resp.item;
  const author = new Author({
      author_id: videoObj.author_user_id.toString(),
      avatar: videoObj.author.avatar,
  });

  // save author
  await author.save();

  const video = new Video({
    video_id: videoObj.id,
    author: author.author_id, // ref
  });

  // save video
  await video.save();

  res.status(201).send({ video })
} catch (err) {
  res.status(400).send(err.message)
}
```

Comment: Thank you alot for solution, it works nicely. Incase I want to check if this author is already exits on DB, then how do I modifly code? It should change something on `author: author._id, // ref`